# Are B5 FOIA exemptions only allowed for communication within the government?

Tags: foia

In the a video from [Peak Prosperity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNxoVFZwMYw) the claim is made that communcation between private individuals outside of the US government and an agency withing the US government can't be legally redacted under B5.

The [FOIA website](https://www.foia.gov/faq.html) describes the B5 exemption as:

> Exemption 5: Privileged communications within or between agencies,
> including those protected by the:
>
> Deliberative Process Privilege (provided the records were created less
> than 25 years before the date on which they were requested)
> Attorney-Work Product Privilege Attorney-Client Privilege

Does the word agency here mean agency of the US government and thus communications with private individuals can't be legally redacted under B5 as asserted in the video?